# No se asocia Card a Customer con la api de MERCADO PAGO

Tags: codeigniter, mercadopago

Hola estoy intentando asociar un token de una tarjeta a un Customer con la api de MercadoPago, ya realice los pasos que dice en la documentación, el Customer lo crea bien, le asocio el card token (creado desde la app movil con el sdk), y me dice status 200 (como si estuviera todo correcto). Pero cuando busco las cards de ese Customer no me muestra ninguna.
¿Qué puede estar pasando??

Este es el **codigo** que estoy usando:

```
$card = $this->mp->post ("/v1/customers/".$customer_id."/cards", array("token" => $token));
```

Este es el **response** que genera:

```
Array
(
[status] => 200
[response] => Array
    (
    )

)
```

Si busco las cards por ese cliente me tira un array vacío. Pero si intento volver a generar una card para ese cliente con el mismo token, me tira inválido card owner.

Comment: **[Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)**.  Por favor [edit] la pregutna y explica por ejemplo, ¿qué significa: `el Customer lo crea s`? explica tu problema de una manera mas clara.

Comment: Ya lo edite mejor que eso imposible. Básicamente no asocia el token al Customer (según la doc oficial de MercadoPago)